# Json error: Cannot read property 'xxx' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am obtaining a @attr value like this:

```
item['@attr']['nowplaying']
```

This works fine when the attribute is present in the json, but if it not there I get a error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nowplaying' of undefined
```

How can I avoid this error?

Comment: not sure I follow, I have no control over the attrr in the json, the api I am using adds it when music is playing and removes it when it not.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (item['@attr']){
    var nowPlaying = item['@attr']['nowplaying']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Test to see if `item['@attr']` has a value that can have properties before you try to access any properties of it.

```
if (item['@attr']) {
   whatever(item['@attr']['nowplaying']);
}
```